# Thunar: "Unable to find or create wastebasket directory" on samba share

Tags: permissions, samba, thunar

I have a samba share directory that is mounted on my machine as:

```
//xxx/home_private  /media/home_private cifs rw,noperm,credentials=/home/xx/samba_perm.txt 0 0
```

When I tried to delete file using Thunar I get an error:

```
"Unable to find or create wastebasket directory"
```

I found some ideas in internet that I should create .Trash-UID folder in the root directory of the mounted share, where UID should corresponds to the UID of the user.

I have assumes that it should correspond to the UID of samba user.
Unfortunately it does not work.

Below part of my smb.conf file:

```
[home_private]
    comment =Home Private Server
    path = /media/xxx/private
    valid users = @home_users
    force user = pi
    read only = No
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

P.S. shift+Delete works fine.

Comment: the UID should correspond to your user, not the Samba user. according to the trash spec on freedesktop.org, Thunar should create this directory on its own, and if it can't, it should just bail out. at least IIRC. seems to be a bug.

Comment: I should be registered on the remote machine with the same UID as on local one, shouldn't I?

Comment: I have no idea; I'm not a Samba expert. but if I was to hazard a guess, I'd say no.